# Is there a way to continue execute script after call 'zsh'?

Tags: shell

I wan to do something after run `zsh` in a script. Such as

```
#!/bin/sh
zsh
echo anything
```

but the `echo anything` doesn't execute. Is it possible?

(I use `zsh` to do something like `source ~/.zshrc`, and i use `oh-my-zsh`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `echo` will execute as soon as the `zsh` completes.  If you intend for the `zsh` to be an interactive shell that lets you type in commands, you can end it by typing Ctrl-D in most terminals.  Then the `echo` will run.

Comment: But nothing print after `zsh` completed. (Ctrl-D works)

Comment: @YongleLin: I think you are mistaken.  For example try writing `zsh -c "echo hello"` instead of just `zsh`.  You should see `hello` and `anything`.

Comment: I use `zsh` to do something like `source ~/.zshrc`(I use `oh-my-zsh`), so the problem is the script stop after `zsh` completed.